# Причастный оборот vs. относительное придаточное

Tags: синтаксис, причастный-оборот

> У окна стоит мальчик, **слушающий музыку**.

Если я понимаю правильно, выделенный фрагмент это причастный оборот. Модифицирую предложение, чтобы сделать относи́тельное прида́точное предложение и на мой взгляд звучит не совсем плохо: "*У окна стоит мальчик, **который слушает музыку***." (Можно сказать так?) Вопрос: что есть хорошее в таком случае в причастном обороте? Kомпактность?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Технически можно обойтись без причастных оборотов. Но они украшают нашу речь, делают ее лаконичной, помогают нам точнее выразить свою мысль, верно расставить смысловые акценты. В некоторых случаях предложение, построенное как альтернатива применению причастного оборота, хоть и понятно, но звучит "не по-русски". Например, попробуйте перестроить следующее предложение, не употребив причастный оборот: "Колеблется на ветру стебелек, с еще не высохшей утренней росой"

Вот некоторые полезные сведения о причастных оборотах, подчерпнутые из сети:

Причастные обороты являются в основном принадлежностью книжно-письменной речи. На это указывал еще Пушкин, говоря о различии между письменной речью и речью разговорной:

"Может ли письменный язык быть совершенно подобным разговорному? Нет, так же, как разговорный язык никогда не может быть совершенно подобным письменному. Не одни местоимения сей и оный, но н причастия вообще и множество слов необходимых обыкновенно избегаются в разговоре. Мы не говорим: карета, скачущая по мосту, слуга, метущий комнату; 
мы говорим: которая скачет, который метет и пр.,— заменяя выразительную краткость причастия вялым оборотом"

Причастные обороты воспринимаются как эстетическая категория художественного текста. Они не только образно описывают, характеризуют предмет, но и представляют его признак в динамике, в процессе его становления, развития, изменения. Они соединяют в себе энергию глагола и описательную экспрессию прилагательного. ( М. Ломоносов так говорил о причастиях: «Они служат к сокращению человеческого слова, заключая в себе глагола и имени силу». ) Именно эта особенность придаёт предмету яркость, образность, динамичность, выразительность. Автор использует причастные обороты для того, чтобы с их помощью воздействовать на чувства читателей или слушателей.
Причастие и причастный оборот в тексте научного стиля не являются выразительным средством. Они служат для уточнения, конкретизации, краткости, сжатости при выражении тех или иных научных определений, служат также для лаконичности, глубины раскрытия научных понятий.

Comment: М_Г: спасибо большое большое! потрясающий ответ, именно такая информация, которая хотела знать!

Answer (score 1):

**У окна стоит мальчик, слушающий музыку.** Всё нормально, нет смысла менять на определительное предложение.

**У окна стоит мальчик, которому нравится слушать музыку.** Здесь причастный оборот невозможен, то есть придаточное определительное является более универсальной конструкцией.

**Вот как Розенталь сравнивает эти параллельные структуры:**

[§211. Причастные обороты](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_01)

7. **Причастные обороты используются для замены синонимичных придаточных определительных предложений в ряде случаев:**

1)      если высказывание **имеет книжный характер**, например Многочисленные факты, накопленные наукой, подтвердили правильность гипотезы, выдвинутой молодым ученым. Ср. также **оттенок торжественности, вносимый в речь такими формами, как ведомый, несомый, влекомый**, редко используемыми в современном языке,

2)      если в сложном предложении **повторяется союзное слово который**, в частности при последовательном подчинении придаточных предложений, например: «На научно-методической конференции, **которая** была посвящена вопросам преподавания иностранных языков, был сделан ряд сообщений, **которые** содержали интересные данные о применении системы программированного обучения» (каждое из придаточных предложений или оба они могут быть заменены причастными оборотами);

3)      **если нужно устранить двузначность**, связанную с возможной различной соотнесенностью союзного слова который, например: «Жирным шрифтом выделены слова в предложениях, которые используются для грамматического разбора» (или используемые, или используемых, в зависимости от смысла предложения);

4)      если высказыванию придается **определенная стилистическими соображениями КРАТКОСТЬ**, например: «Обоз стоял на большом мосту, тянувшемся через широкую реку... Впереди за рекой пестрела громадная гора, усеянная домами и церквами...» (Чехов).

Используя преимущества причастного оборота, следует вместе с тем учитывать такой недостаток причастий, как **их неблагозвучие в случае скопления форм на -ший и -вший.**

Comment: Arina: спасибо за ответ! если быть честной, I skimmed over your text и оооооооочень тяжело читать/понимать (at least for me). попробую еще раз сейчас 
PD: "У окна стоит мальчик, которому нравится слушать музыку." - мой вариант без глагола "нравиться"

Comment: Вариант с причастием короче, поэтому по возможности используется именно он. Когда мы используем определительные предложения: 1) когда причастный оборот  не получается построить, то есть он не может включить тот объём  информации, которую можно без проблем  поместить в предложение. 2) в сложных конструкциях, когда сочетают оборот и предложение, чтобы не повторяться.